Why is libopenblas from numpy so big?
We are deploying an open source application based on numpy that includes libopenblas.{cryptic string}.gfortran-win32.dll.  It is part of the Python numpy package.  This dll is over 27MB in size.  I'm curious why it is so big and where I can find the source for it to see for myself.
Ultimately I'd like to see if it can be more limited in size for my application.
Thanks

OpenBLAS includes many optimized kernels for different CPU architectures and instruction sets. This is why the DLL is too large.
Alternatives like BLIS and Intel's Math Kernel Library (MKL) exist. You can give a try to them if you consider.
You can also build the library from the beginning and strip off the unnecessary parts while building, maybe.

Thanks, that's pretty much my working theory,too.  We are trying to deploy a sample application that users can run on their own python systems, do recompiling BLAS is not an option.  For a precompiled/CX-Frozen executable, it may be more reasonable.
